# How to edit value of an attribute of an element of a web page which is loaded in ifarme

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm creating a web page and I have to control iframe from parent page.
As the title I need to edit an element's attribute which is in iframe.
I want do this to enter some text to a text box which is in iframe

```
document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.getElementByName('q').attributes('value')='abcde';
```

This code didn't work.
Here,src of iframe is google.com

Please suggest me a method/code to do this.
Thank you.

Comment: Would you be able to post your code as a snippet or JSFiddle? [See How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This will only work in same origin, for obvious security issues.

Answer (score 0):

To add text with js you need to use innerHTML or textContent. Attribute value is usualy used for input types.

Something like this should work:

document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.getElementByName('q').innerHTML='abcde';